# check for samaccount name, if exists, add next letter of first name, check again - recursive

Tags: c#, string, powershell, active-directory, substring

Looking to build an account creation app/script [scope undecided atm] and not sure how to handle the samaccountname if it exists already. 
What I want to happen is, if, say,  john smith already has a same account name of jsmith and jane smith is being created, that jsmith is detected, then the script checks for jasmith, if it exists, it will go to jansmith and so on.

I have not even attempted to try this string manipulation as I really do not have an idea where to start.

Thanks, 
JCGee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$FirstName = 'Jane';
$LastName = 'Smith';

for ($i = 1; $i -le $FirstName.Length; $i++) {
    $Account = $null;
    $Identity = $FirstName.Substring(0,$i) + $LastName;
    $Account = Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity;
    if ($Account -eq $null) {
        New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Identity -Name $Identity;
        break;
    };
}
```

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity` will raise an error when `$Identity` doesn't exist. It's better to use `Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$Identity'"` here.

Comment: Excellent, finally got around to testing this and that little fix worked @Ansgar Wiechers. I am trying to run it so I can have more than one person with the same first, last, display name, but the samaccount name will be different.  However, when i try this, i get "An attempt was made to add an object to the directory with a name already in use".   My Domain is medium size and we get people with same first/last names quite a bit.   How can I get around this error to allow the same name?   Instead of -Name $Identity, I need it to be -Name $LastName + ", " + $FirstName.

Comment: @JCGee You can't create 2 objects with the same distinguished name. Either create the 2nd object in a different OU (impractical) or create it with a different canonical name (`-Name` parameter).

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar Wiechers.  Just tested on our live domain, could have sworn that we had same name users in same OUs, but they arent.  Our domain actually has many OUs by department so chances of running into the same name in one is sort of low.

Answer (score 1):

I had much the same issue, but i did not want any powershell dependencies

Here is my more traditional C# that I used to create AD users. Search *UserPrincipal* to learn more.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName + ":389");
        string FirstName = "Jane";
        string LastName = "Smith";

        for (int i = 1; i <= FirstName.Length; i++)
        {
            string username = LastName + FirstName.Remove(i);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
            if ((object)user == null) //user doesn't exists
            {
                #region Add User
                try
                {
                    UserPrincipal userex = new UserPrincipal(ctx, username, password, true);
                    userex.GivenName = firstname;
                    userex.Surname = lastname;
                    userex.DisplayName = firstname + " " + lastname;
                    userex.ExpirePasswordNow();
                    userex.Description = _UserDescr;
                    userex.Save();
                    break;
                }
                catch
                {
                    //
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the c# approach.